# Making REST API call using curl to Bluemix Predictive Modeling service

Tags: html, web-services, rest, curl, ibm-cloud

I would like to create HTTP GET request to REST API using the curl tool that comes with the Cloud Foundry command line interface (`cf`). The content/format   of the request is described [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/PredictiveModeling/index-gentopic1.html#pm_service_api), under "Retrieving a list of all currently deployed models:" subtitle. In short, the description gives me the url that I can make the request to, it also gives me the following "request example":
Content-Type: */*

Parameters: 

       Query Parameters:

              accesskey: access_key from env.VCAP_SERVICES
I know how to retrieve all necessary parameters (i.e. the access keys, etc). The problem is that I am not sure how to interpret the above "request example" (is it header or body of the request?) and how to create curl command that will properly send the request.

I want to briefly describe what I have tried so far. When I try:
`cf curl -X GET "http://{my_url}/model?accesskey={my_access_key}"`
I always get the following response:

```
{
   "code": 10000,
   "description": "Unknown request",
   "error_code": "CF-NotFound"
}
```

, when I try:
`cf curl -X 'GET' http://{my_url}/model?accesskey={my_access_key}`
, I think I actually get a response from the server:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenerver I try to use just "normal" curl (not the one that comes with the `cf` command line interface) the Bluemix Predictive Modeling service doesn't respond at all - the connection always times out. I'm not sure why, since Bluemix documentation says that any programming language can be used to make the REST API calls.
 In the future I would also like to use POST requests - an explanation of how to make one would be very helpful too.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to "bind" an instance of the Predictive Model service to an app. When you have done it, you will have a "Show credentials" link below the app widget in your Bluemix dashboard. Click "Show credentials", and you will see a JSON object (which happens to be the VCAP_SERVICES value that Bluemix sets as environment variable for your app), for example:

```
{
  "pm-20": [
    {
      "name": "Predictive Modeling-i6",
      "label": "pm-20",
      "plan": "free",
      "credentials": {
        "url": "https://ibmpmsrvus1.pmservice.ibmcloud.com:8443/pm/v1",
        "access_key": "xxxyyyzzz"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(I have just removed my own credentials).

Finally for the Curl command, use the "url" above as root of your API, and add a query parameter "?accesskey=xxxyyyzzz" (whatever credentials you have on your own) to all API calls. For example, I add /model to my URL to query my list of models (none created):

```
curl -X GET "https://ibmpmsrvus1.pmservice.ibmcloud.com:8443/pm/v1/model?accesskey=xxxyyyzzz"
```

which returns

```
[]
```

(as I have not created any models). Note that you will likely need to quote the URL, since the access key contains characters that may mess up your shell command.

I explicitly used "-X GET": You will want to do "-X PUT" in some commands (PUT HTTP method), and most likely you can use "-d @" to upload a file as form data payload:

```
 curl -X PUT -d @mymodelfile "https://..."
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I already tried using methods you described and none of them work. I also should have mentioned that I am using curl that comes with Cloud Foundry command line interface ("cf") - my mistake. Please see the updated question.